# Pub sub pattern created Queues and Topics on Azure Service Bus with Rebus

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

The app below is tweaked to work with Azure Service Bus.
https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/PubSub

However, below are created.

**Queues**

error

publisher

subscriber

**Topics**

messages_datetimemessage__messages: subscriber

messages_stringmessage__messages: subscriber

messages_timespanmessage__messages: subscriber

**My question**

is that is this correct?

And is it possible to reduce the number of artifacts that are created? For example, reduce to only one topic, because topic is used for pub sub.

**Update**

I need to use Pub sub pattern with one Topic and one or two subscriptions if possible.

However, I have got an error below:

> System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=One or more
>   errors occurred. (Could not publish to topic 'order')
>   Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at Publisher.Program.Main() in
>   C:_MyLab\ReBus\PubSub\Publisher\Program.cs:line 43
>
> Inner Exception 1: RebusApplicationException: Could not publish to
>   topic 'order'
>
> Inner Exception 2: InvalidOperationException: Cannot open a Topic
>   client for entity type Queue.
>   TrackingId:5c380af2-ad8f-4788-85b8-5427dd7873e4_B4,
>   SystemTracker:myapp:Queue:order, Timestamp:2019-04-29T22:31:57
>   TrackingId:9c3e0c40-4410-4102-a705-86a6528cd030_B4,
>   SystemTracker:myapp:Queue:order, Timestamp:2019-04-29T22:31:57
>   TrackingId:401a15d284ad44989f5e451c963d81e5_G16,
>   SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2019-04-29T22:31:57

`UseAzureServiceBus` seems wrong, because it is using queue

```
class Publisher
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
            {
                Configure.With(activator)
                    .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warn))  
                    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Consts.ServiceBusConnectionString, Consts.Order))                   
                    .Start();

                 activator.Bus.Advanced.Topics.Publish(Consts.Order, new StringMessage("Hello there, I'm a publisher!")).Wait();

            }

            }
```

`UseAzureServiceBus` seems wrong, because it is using queue. Is the Handler able to handle message?

```
class Subscriber
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
            {
                activator.Register(() => new Handler());

                Configure.With(activator)
                    .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warn))                   
                    .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Consts.ServiceBusConnectionString, Consts.Order))
                    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<StringMessage>(Consts.Order))
                    .Start();

                activator.Bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe(Consts.Order);

                Console.WriteLine("This is Subscriber 1");
                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Quitting...");
            }
        }
    }

    class Handler : IHandleMessages<StringMessage>, IHandleMessages<DateTimeMessage>, IHandleMessages<TimeSpanMessage>
    {
        public async Task Handle(StringMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got string: {0}", message.Text);
        }

        public async Task Handle(DateTimeMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got DateTime: {0}", message.DateTime);
        }

        public async Task Handle(TimeSpanMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got TimeSpan: {0}", message.TimeSpan);
        }
    }
```

The code above create an Order queue, which is not what I want.

I want a topic, and one or two subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Rebus pretty much encourages you to use .NET types as topics, which in this case means that the topics

- `messages_datetimemessage__messages`
- `messages_stringmessage__messages`
- `messages_timespanmessage__messages`

get created, because you publish events of types `DateTimeMessage`, `StringMessage`, and `TimeSpanMessage` (all residing in the `Messages` namespace in the `Messages` assembly).

If that is not what you want, Rebus allows you to publish to custom topics like so:

```
await bus.Advanced.Publish("my-topic", new DateTimeMessage(...))`;
```

which in this case will result in the creation of a single topic: `my-topic`.

The subscriber(s) will need to subscribe accordingly:

```
await bus.Advanced.Subscribe("my-topic");
```

Keep in mind that there's no filtering of the types of events published to a topic, so the subscriber above will receive anything published to the `my-topic` topic, regardless of whether it is capable of handling it.

Comment: I will test it and update here. On a similar question on ASB, is it possible to setup on Azure, not Rebus, to filter message based on headers to different subscriptions instead of sending to all subscriptions?

Comment: It probably is. I seem to recall having used "SQL filters", or something like that, on subscriptions once. I'm not particularly fond of the idea though, as topics (at least in my mind) ought to be enough for expressing interest in messages... but that's just my opinion 

Comment: Thanks. It is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters

Comment: On the Rebus for ASB Topic, Can Publish() method publishes to a topic, and Subcriber subscribes to a subscription? From the code you showed me, my-topic seems like a queue to me.

Comment: In Azure Service Bus lingo, `await bus.Subscribe("my-topic")` will create a topic called `my-topic`, under which it will then create a subscription that forwards all received messages to the subscriber's input queue. This way, messages are always received from a queue.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I meant if a topic called 'Order' is created, and two subscriptions called 'OrderPlaced' and 'OrderPaid' are created, how can I use them with Rebus?

Comment: It's not possible to name the subscriptions with Rebus. When you say `await bus.Subscribe("topic-name")` you simply _bind_ the subscriber's input queue to the topic `topic-name` – that's what a subscription represents, really: It's a binding between a topic and a subscriber's queue.

Comment: Please see my update on OP. I tried to implement the code based on your comments, but I have got an error.

Comment: It seems like Azure Service Bus does not accept topics and queues with the same names. Here, you're trying to use the name `order` for your input queue AND your topic. I suggest you come up with another topic name, or simply use Rebus' built-in topic naming strategy by doing this in your publisher: `await bus.Publish(new StringMessage(...));` and this in your subscriber: `await bus.Subscribe<StringMessage>();`

Comment: your last suggestion is the same as  the code on the OP of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833226/pub-sub-pattern-with-centralized-subscription-storage-using-azure-service-bus/55834042

Comment: The purpose of the thread is to find out if it is possible to use one topic and one or two subscriptions for the topic. If possible, can you please provide advice or code sample?

Comment: This method only accepts queue, not topic? UseAzureServiceBus(Consts.ServiceBusConnectionString, Consts.Order)

Comment: Do you have a chance to receive my previous comments?

Comment: With Rebus, you never receive messages directly from topics. With Rebus, you 1) start a bus instance with a queue name, which then can be thought of as the identity of your bus instance, and then you 2) subscribe to any number of topics, using that bus, which – underneath the covers – BINDS the subscribed topics to your input queue, but creating a subscription that forwards messages to the queue. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Is it possible customise the name of topic, e.g. change messages_stringmessage__messages to myMessage ?

Comment: Yes, [`ITopicNameConvention`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Topic/ITopicNameConvention.cs) decides how .NET types are converted into topic names, so you can register your own implementation to affect how that's done... you can register your implementation like this: `Configure.With(...)
 .(...)
 .Options(o => o.Register<ITopicNameConvention>(c => new MyTopicNameConvention()))
 .Start();`